# Angular JS - Error: $http:badreq Bad Request Configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning Angular JS. I am trying to create a mock portal that displays Daily Messages. I have stored my daily messages in a database table.

```
create table DailyMsg(Sno int primary key, msg varchar(max));
```

Then I created a service using factory in AngularJS.

```
 public class DailyMsgsController : Controller
    {
        private amenEntities1 db = new amenEntities1();

        // GET: DailyMsgs
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Json(db.DailyMsgs.ToList(),JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

I tested the URL and it works fine, it returns the expected data in the JSON format

```
https://localhost:44329/DailyMsgs
```

Now, I wanted to display this data on my HomePage. But it doesn't work. On inspecting the page it shows me the error

```
Error: $http:badreq
Bad Request Configuration
Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: undefined
```

My Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//Daily Messages Service Function
myApp.factory('DailyMsgService', function ($http) {
    DailyMsgObj = {};
    DailyMsgObj.DisplayDailyMsg = function () {

        var Msg;

        Msg = $http({method: 'GET', URL: '/DailyMsgs/Index'}).
            then(function (response){
            return response.data;
        });

        return Msg;
    }

    return DailyMsgObj;
});



myApp.controller('HomePageController', function ($scope, DailyMsgService) {
    DailyMsgService.DisplayDailyMsg().then(function (result) {

        $scope.DailyMsg = result;

    });
});
```

My HomePage

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HomePageController">
        {{DailyMsg}}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../AngularControllers/HomePageController.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are learning Angular 1 in 2022? You are aware that Angular 2 was released in September 2016, right? Any reason why you are learning a long deprecated framework? I hope it's only to maintain old projects

Comment: I took a course on udemy. Just trying its examples to get an idea of angular.

Comment: Could you suggest me a better way i can achieve this purpose? I want an admin module in my website where admin updates the msg and it gets reflected in the main page.

Comment: My point is, since you are learning something, why learn a framework that's long deprecated and nobody uses anymore, instead of a current technology? You are learning Angular 1, but Angular 2 was a complete and profound rewrite back in 2016, and since then, there has been a major version every 6 months. The current version is 13, I believe.